# Google Analytics joins to Excel File for Data Model

Tags: excel, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, data-modeling

I am looking to understand how I can join fields in Google Analytics to Excel? I am unable to see a way in which I can directly join these fields. Has anyone carried out this task before?

GA data:

GA      GA example
ProfileID       ga:48632576
AccountName     nara
PropertyName        http://www.new.com
ProfileName     UK NFD (All Parameters)
ga_userType     New Visitor
ga_source       (direct)
ga_medium       (none)
ga_deviceCategory       desktop
ga_country      (not set)
ga_date     20170714
ga_users        1
ga_newUsers     1
ga_sessions     1
ga_bounces      0
ga_sessionDuration      237
ga_pageviews        4
ga_avgTimeOnPage        78.66666667
ga_transactions     0
ga_transactionRevenue       0
ga_uniquePurchases      0

BookingId   5475635
BookingFamilyID {13F34581-E2AD-41A5-946A-04F18222D988}
BookedDate  28/07/2012 00:00
PublicUserId    {055E3FFC-A62C-4468-A17D-A252B92A70EB}
TotalClientCost 1
BookingType Flight
BookingTypeId   1
BookingMethodId 1
BookingMethod   Online
EstabId 126039
Estab   Universal Hotel Florida
LocationId  219015
Location    Magaluf
ProvinceId  54859
Province    Majorca
EmailGuid   {506995D0-D5DE-462D-9C6A-199BBB1A6109}
DomainBookedOn  travelrepublic.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to pull one column from the second set, you can use vlookup.  If you want to pull / combine multiple columns, then either write a small script (under Developer optional menu) or use PowerPivot (free Excel add in) and then define a relationship between the two sheets